# Play2.1 JSON Format with Empty String Validation

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

I am attempting to validate JSON when unmarshalling to an object in Play2.1. The Format object I have defined only validates when a field is absent in the JSON, but I want to validate that fields are nonEmpty strings. Is this possible? I've tried specifying the minLength() constraint (as seen [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJsonCombinators)) in the reads() call, but I get a compiler error saying minLength can't be found. Is that only for the tuple approach?

See the following Specs2 Junit test which fails now, but should pass when the constraint is defined properly:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import play.api.libs.json._

class SimpleValidation extends SpecificationWithJUnit{

  private val badPayload: JsValue = Json.obj(
    "simpleValue1" -> "mySimpleValue", // Comment this line out to pass test
    "simpleValue2" -> ""
  )

  "An IssueFormat" should {
    "validate when unmarshalling" in {

      badPayload.validate[SimpleObj].fold(
        valid = (res => {
          // Fail if valid
          failure("Payload should have been invalid")
        }),
        invalid = (e => {
          // Should be one error
          e.length mustBeEqualTo(1)
        }))

    }
  }
}

import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class SimpleObj(simpleValue1: String, simpleValue2: String)
object SimpleObj {
  val simpleReads = (
    (__ \ "simpleValue1").read[String] and
    (__ \ "simpleValue2").read[String])(SimpleObj.apply _) // read[String](minLength(0)) yields compiler error
  val simpleWrites = (
    (__ \ "simpleValue1").write[String] and
    (__ \ "simpleValue2").write[String])(unlift(SimpleObj.unapply))
  implicit val simpleFormat: Format[SimpleObj] = Format(simpleReads, simpleWrites)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the Play2.1 documentation some more, I was able to add a custome read validator. If you replace the SimpleObj from the original question, with the following, the test case will pass. Not sure if there is a simpler way to do this, but this definitely works:

```
object SimpleObj {
  // defines a custom reads to be reused
  // a reads that verifies your value is not equal to a give value
  def notEqual[T](v: T)(implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[T] = Reads.filterNot(ValidationError("validate.error.unexpected.value", v))(_ == v)

  implicit val simpleReads = (
    (__ \ "simpleValue1").read[String](notEqual("")) and
    (__ \ "simpleValue2").read[String](notEqual("")))(SimpleObj.apply _)

  val simpleWrites = (
    (__ \ "simpleValue1").write[String] and
    (__ \ "simpleValue2").write[String])(unlift(SimpleObj.unapply))
  implicit val simpleFormat: Format[SimpleObj] = Format(simpleReads, simpleWrites)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the minLength in Reads:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
```

Then minLength should be available, however, try this format instead:

```
implicit val simpleReads = (
  (__ \ "simpleValue1").read(minLength[String](1)) and
  (__ \ "simpleValue2").read(minLength[String](1))(SimpleObj.apply _)
```